# django static files with a different path

Tags: django

I'm trying to make the local development work with everything under a /abc. 
For example, instead of http://localhost:8080 I want everything to be at something like http://localhost:8080/abcd

I was able to achieve this by updating the url.py with the following:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^abcd/admin/', include(admin.site.urls), name='admin'),
    url(r'^abcd/search/?$', views.search, name='search'),
    url(r'^abcd/$', views.index, name='root')
)

# Force Django to serve static assets, if this is not the production
if settings.PRODUCTION is False:
    urlpatterns += patterns('', (
        r'^abcd/static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
            'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT
        }
    ))
```

Now I can view the pages with http://localhost:8080/abcd but the rendering does not show up correctly because of the static files. I need the static files to be served at http://localhost:8080/abcd/static/ and for it to work with all the pages.

Is there a simple way to make it work?  I tried doing the above and it doesn't seem to work.  I'm super new to django so I don't fully understand how I can achieve what I'm trying to do.  Any help from experts would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It should work.

```
      urlpatterns = patterns('',
           url(r'^abcd/', views.index, name='root')
           url(r'^abcd/admin/', include(admin.site.urls), name='admin'),
           url(r'^abcd/search/?$', views.search, name='search')
        )

     # Force Django to serve static assets, if this is not the production
     if settings.PRODUCTION is False:
          urlpatterns += patterns('', (
              r'^abcd/static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
                   'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT
              }
         ))
```

change settings.py

```
     STATIC_URL = '/abcd/static/'
     STATICFILES_DIRS = [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
     ]
```

Comment: Thanks Hasan!  It turns out that I had to also modify the settins.py file to make it work.

Comment: change settings.py file STATIC_URL = '/abcd/static/'
     STATICFILES_DIRS = [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
     ]